# How to pass sessionStorage contents to a Jade variable?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

As you might know, there's this **sessionStorage** concept in **HTML5** and I want make use of it for a simple two factor authentication case (on an **ExpressJS** app)... I have this logic/code on my **jade view**:

```
extends ../layout
block content
  - var two_factor = user.two_factor
  - var liveToken = user.liveToken
  - var inputToken = sessionStorage.userToken
  if two_factor == true
    if liveToken != inputToken
      //- Show input for entering user_token
    else
      //- Render Content
  else
    if liveToken == inputToken
      //- Render Content
```

On the server side, every time a user logs in I generate a random 6-digit token code that I send to the user's phone and then what I want to do is (via jade) do the validation as shown here: Basically if a user has two factor auth enabled I want to render only an input field for the user to enter the code and then store that user-entered token into the HTML5 sessionStorage to refresh the page later with the full content visible... Notice I have the **liveToken/inputToken** comparison for both cases of my two_factor condition because if a user doesn't has two factor auth enabled both values ideally would be **undefined**.

The problem I'm having right now is that my **inputToken** variable is returning this error:

> Cannot read property 'userToken' of undefined

I know this is happening because Jade variables are interpreted/executed on the server side and the server doesn't know what **sessionStorage** is (because that's an Object of the client side); But I want to know if it is possible to accomplish what I wanna do here in some way (for example making jade interpret that inputToken variable **on the client** thus have it's value available for the later condition after refreshing the view)...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to have acces to the inputToken from client, I think you do not have other choice than sending it with cookie to the server. If I have well understand what is sessionStorage, it is here to keep data between navigation and avoid sending them to the server like cookie does.

Comment: Indeed, I don't want to send the inputToken to the server, I want to keep the comparison process on the client side, hence the use of sessionStorage. I just need Jade to store/recognize that variable for me

Comment: If you want to do the comparison on the client side you can't use jade (except if your jade template is interpreted on client side but in this case client will have access to the liveToken value)

Comment: Ended up using a normal session variable with a redirect and some middleware for this... Any solution to achieve the desired implementation (the one shown in the question) would be nice... I just think it might be useful if there were some way to access sessionStorage from a Jade template and interact with it's contents.